# Applying multiple filters to list of tuples

Tags: python, filter, tuples

I am looking for an efficient, pythonic way to apply multiple filters to a list of tuples.

As an example, assume filters like this:

```
def f1(t): return t[3]<10
def f2(t): return t[0]!=1
def f3(t): return t[1] in ("lisa","eric")
def f4(t): return t[3]>2
```

And n-tuples (i.e. db-records) like this:

```
tuples=[
(0,'tom','...',8),
(1,'john','...',17),
(2,'lisa','...',1),
(3,'eric','...',18)
]
```

The following works:

```
def nFilter(filters,tuples):
    if filters and tuples:
        return nFilter(filters,filter(filters.pop(),tuples))
    else: return tuples
```

With results like:

```
>>> nFilter([f1,f2,f3],tuples)
[(2, 'lisa', '...', 1)]
```

and

```
>>> nFilter([f1,f2,f3,f4],tuples)
[]
```

But I'm wondering if there is a more direct way; what I had in mind is something like function composition (i.e `f1(f2(...fn(tuples)...))`), for an arbitrary list of functions. There are references to a [functional library](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/howto/functional.html#the-functional-module) containing a `compose` function in the docs, but the links are all dead.

Also, since I'm planning on using this on fairly large data sets, and possibly with a large number of filters in a production web service, it must be efficient, and I can't really say if this solution is.

Any suggestions or improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 33):

### Improvement:  Replace recursion with iteration

There isn't really "a composition function for an arbitrary list of functions"; however, it is pretty easy to build the filter chain with a simple for-loop:

```
def nFilter(filters, tuples):
    for f in filters:
        tuples = filter(f, tuples)
    return tuples
```

### Improvement:  Order filters by restrictiveness and speed

Chained iterators are so fast that the total running time will tend to be dominated by the calls to predicate functions.

The best outcome can be had by ordering the predicates to minimize the total work.  In general, it is better to put cheap tests before expensive tests and to put more restrictive tests before tests that don't filter out many cases.

### Example

In this example, the predicates have about the same cost (a function call, tuple indexing, and comparison to a constant), but they vary in restrictiveness (the `t[2]==4` filters-out 80% of the cases while the`t[0]>1` and `t[1]<3` each only filter-out 40% of the data).

```
>>> from itertools import product

>>> filters = [lambda t: t[2]==4, lambda t: t[0]>1, lambda t: t[1]<3]
>>> for tup in nFilter(filters, product(range(5), repeat=3)):
        print(tup)

(2, 0, 4)
(2, 1, 4)
(2, 2, 4)
(3, 0, 4)
(3, 1, 4)
(3, 2, 4)
(4, 0, 4)
(4, 1, 4)
(4, 2, 4)
```

### Notes hoisted-up from the comments

- The filter functions make zero applications of the predicate when the input iterable is empty. It is like doing a for-loop over an empty list.
- Each filter reduces the amount of data fed into the enclosing filter.  Accordingly, each filter gets only gets applied to data that has made it through the previous filters.
- Don't worry about the `lambda` in the example.  It makes the same function as a regular `def`.  It is just a convenient way of writing the list of filters.
- In Python 3, the [*filter()*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) function was updated to return a iterator instead of a list.  In Python 2, you can achieve the same effect using [*itertools.ifilter()*](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) instead [*filter()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#filter).

Comment: Good answer - but the latter approach will keep applying filters even if tuple list is empty.

Comment: @Raymond I've done some quick timeit tests using only the `lambda x: None` filter, timing *only* the iteration of the iterator. Once chained 10 times (5 usec), and once chained 10'000 times (392 usec). So there is some overhead.

Comment: Interesting - but still the benchmark sketch below seems to rank this solution 3rd - could it be because of the overhead caused by calling ifilter with the remaining filters? In that case maybe using `ifilter` in @BigYellowCactus' while loop would be even faster?

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Using generators and lambdas when a simple loop is just fine adds a lot of unnecessarry overhead. Using `filter` instead of `ifilter` *is faster* if you're going to consume the entire generator in the last step. It also enables you to exit the entire loop earlier. It's neither *inexplicable* nor *unexpected*.

Answer (score 32):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
filters = (f1,f2,f3,f4)
filtered_list = filter( lambda x: all(f(x) for f in filters), your_list )
```

This has the advantage that as soon as a single filter returns `False`, that list element won't be included.

Comment: This is so much better than the other answers.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend using the following pattern for liberally applying a series/chain of filters on generators:

```
from functools import reduce, partial
from itertools import ifilter

filtered = reduce(lambda s,f: ifilter(f,s), filter_set, unfiltered)
```

In a nutshell, it sets up a chain of filters from left to right on the generator and returns the generator that is the result of applying all the filters on the original.

If you are looking to get a list, the following would suffice:

```
[reduce(lambda s,f: ifilter(f,s), (f1,f2,f3,), tuples)]
```

and if you are looking to get a single function, you can define one as:

```
chain_filters = partial(reduce, lambda s,f: ifilter(f,s))
```

and use as:

```
[chain_filters((f1,f2,f3,), tuples)]
```

Note that, this solution does not compose the filters (as in `all()`), but chains them. If you are using some heavy computation, you would want to put the more aggressive filter towards the beginning of the chain, e.g. a bloom filter before a database query filter, etc.

Answer (score 6):

A generator expression seems the most idiomatic approach (and you get laziness for free):

```
def nFilter(filters, tuples):
    return (t for t in tuples if all(f(t) for f in filters))
```

Or the equivalent (and arguably more readable):

```
def nFilter(filters, tuples):
    for tuple in tuples:
        if all(filter(tuple) for filter in filters):
            yield tuple
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, no fancy itertools or the like here, just avoiding the overhead of recursion and generators using a simple loop:

```
def for_loop(filters, tuples):
    for f in filters:
        tuples = filter(f, tuples)
        if not tuples: 
            return tuples
    return tuples
```

---

Here's a little dirty benchmark:

```
import datetime
from itertools import ifilter
from timeit import Timer

def f1(t): return t[3]<10
def f2(t): return t[0]!=1
def f3(t): return t[1] in ("lisa","eric")
def f4(t): return t[3]>2

def original(filters,tuples):
    if filters and tuples:
        return original(filters,filter(filters.pop(),tuples))
    else: 
        return tuples

def filter_lambda_all(filters, tuples):
    return filter(lambda t: all(f(t) for f in filters), tuples)

def loop(filters, tuples):
    while filters and tuples:
        f = filters[0]
        del filters[0]
        tuples = filter(f, tuples)
    return tuples

def pop_loop(filters, tuples):
    while filters and tuples:
        tuples = filter(filters.pop(), tuples)
    return tuples

def for_loop(filters, tuples):
    for f in filters:
        tuples = filter(f, tuples)
        if not tuples: 
            return tuples
    return tuples


def with_ifilter(filters, tuples):
    for f in filters:
        tuples = ifilter(f, tuples)
    return tuples

_filters = [f1, f2, f3, f4]

def time(f):
    def t():
        return [    (0,'tom','...',8),
                    (1,'john','...',17),
                    (2,'lisa','...',1),
                    (3,'eric','...',18)
                ]*1000
    for i in xrange(4):
        list(f(_filters[i:] * 15,t()))

if __name__=='__main__':
    for f in (original,filter_lambda_all,loop,pop_loop,with_ifilter,for_loop):
        t = Timer(lambda: time(f))
        d = t.timeit(number=400)
        print f.__name__, d
```

Result:

> original 7.23815271085
>   filter_lambda_all 14.1629812265
>   loop 7.23445844453
>   pop_loop 7.3084566637
>   with_ifilter 9.2767674205
>   for_loop 7.02854999945

Comment: Great,just started benchmarking it all myself, and here it is:-)

Comment: Wow, you're stacking it in your favour here. For example, `f1` and `f2` will when composed result in the empty set for your input tuples, so while the other solutions run through all three or four hundred filters, your solution will exit after just two loops. Why don't you test with realistic data that will actually yield a non-empty result?

Comment: `timeit` is much better for benchmarking than `datetime` as that is the purpose of the module ...

Comment: On closer inspection, you need `f4` as well as `f1` and `f2` to eliminate all tuples, so only the list `list(nFilter([f1,f2,f3]*100,tuples))` will be nonempty, containing lots of `(2,'lisa','...',1)` tuples.

Comment: Would `f=filters.pop()` instead of `f=filters[0]` and `del filters[0]` have any effect either way?

Comment: @Alfred That's a good idea, because popping off the end of a list is much faster than deleting (or popping) from the front. But you'd need to reverse `filters` before entering the `while` loop so as to apply them in the right order.

Comment: @mgilson Sorry, I was just lazy. Fixed it :-)

Comment: @AlfredBratterud I replaced the `while` loop with a `for` loop, and this is even faster.

Answer (score 4):

similar to *@Raymond Hettinger,*

Although, i suggest using ifilter from itertools as a generator.

```
from itertools import ifilter

def nFilter(filters,tuples):
      return ifilter(lambda t: all(f(t) for f in filters), tuples)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to @tokland you could define

```
superFilter=lambda x:all(filter(x) for filter in filters)
newTuples=filter(superFilter,tuples)
```

Or the one liner

```
 newTuples=filter(lambda x:all(filter(x) for filter in filters),tuples)
```

If you only do this super-filtering once this is superior.